# Error when adding a value to Map<String, ArrayList<String>>

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist, hashmap

I'm getting the error

```
error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to ArrayList<String>
         crazyMap.put(company, day);
```

when I run this code

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> crazyMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
String company = "myCompany";
String day = "Monday";
crazyMap.put(company, day);
```

How can I go about formatting the 'day' parameter to satisfy the type error?

Comment: Create an ArrayList, add the String to it, add the list to the map.

Answer (score 0):

What is your goal with the data structure?

Should crazyMap store a company that maps to a single day like you are trying to add above? If so, try:

```
Map<String, String> crazyMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
String company = "myCompany";
String day = "Monday";
crazyMap.put(company, day);
```

Or do you want crazyMap to have a company that maps to multiple days?  Something like this:

```
Map<String, Collection<String>> crazyMap = new HashMap<String, Collection<String>>();
Collection<String> days = new ArrayList<String>();
days.add("Monday");
crazyMap.put("myCompany", days);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of bothering with the `ArrayList` yourself, I would recommend to use an already existing type with designed for multiple values: [Guavas](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) Multimap ([explanation](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap); [JavaDoc](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)).

Instead of doing this:

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> crazyMap = new HashMap<>();
crazyMap.put("myCompany", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Monday")));
```

You can do this:

```
Multimap<String, String> crazyMap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
crazyMap.put("myCompany", "Monday");
```

This also avoids ugly stuff like:

```
ArrayList<String> items; 
if (crazyMap.containsKey("myCompany")) {
    items = crazyMap.get("myCompany");
} else {
    items = new ArrayList<>();
}
items.add("Tuesday");
crazyMap.put("myCompany", items);
```

Guava cares about creating the collection for you, if it doesn't exist. Just call:

```
crazyMap.put("myCompany", "Tuesday");
```

and everything is done.

One disadvantage is, that the used interface is `MultiMap` which doesn't extend `Map`. This means you have to "weaken" the variable type to `MultiMap`, like:

```
public void someMethod(MultiMap<K, V> multimap)
```

instead of:

```
public void someMethod(Map<K, Collection<V>> multiMap)
```

Read more about the differences here: ["Multimap Is Not A Map"](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap_Is_Not_A_Map).

---

You can find the newest version of Guava on the [maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava).